# How to check if mouse doesn't move in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to write a function that returns true if mouse doesn't move for given amount of time.

I've tried Mouse.GetPosition() but it keeps returning the same coordinates.

```cs
private bool MouseNotMoves(int time)
{
    Point currentMouseCoord = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
    TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,0);
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

    while (timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds <= time)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        timeSpan = DateTime.Now - start;
        Point newMouseCoord = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
        if (currentMouseCoord != newMouseCoord) 
            start = DateTime.Now;

        currentMouseCoord = newMouseCoord;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I want to get mouse coordinates when calling the function and then again after some time and compare them, the problem is that the function always returns true after exact given time. When i try debugging the mouse coordinates never change even if I move the mouse. 
I'm quite new to programing so if there's a better way to achieve this I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Better use a timer (e.g. a DispatcherTimer) that is stopped and restarted in a MouseMove handler.

Comment: Or just store the timestamp of the last MouseMove call, and check it whenever necessary. It's not exactly clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Did you think about inverting your logic? I mean, you could write an async function which is going to first subscribe to MouseMoved event (if it happens you set some flag) then it asynchronously waits for Delay (your input TimeSpan) and then it returns if the flag was set.

Comment: _the problem is that the function always returns true after given time_ - The function cannot return anything else than true because it does not contain a `return false;`.

Comment: What i meant was that the function always return true exactly after given time, Mouse.GetPosition() never changes its coordinates, what can be causing that?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of what I meant in the comments by inverting the logic. It's quite dirty, but I believe it highlights the idea.

```
    private bool _mouseMoved;

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyTextBlock.Text = (await IfMouseMoved(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4))).ToString();
    }

    private async Task<bool> IfMouseMoved(TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        MouseMove += MainWindow_MouseMove;
        try
        {
            _mouseMoved = false;
            await Task.Delay(timeSpan);
            return _mouseMoved;
        }
        finally
        {
            MouseMove -= MainWindow_MouseMove;
        }
    }

    private void MainWindow_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _mouseMoved = true;
    }
```

**UPD.** The same solution can be written concisely using local function for the callback:

```
    private async Task<bool> IfMouseMoved(TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        var mouseMoved = false;

        void MouseMovedCallback(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseMoved = true;
        }

        MouseMove += MouseMovedCallback;
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(timeSpan);
            return mouseMoved;
        }
        finally
        {
            MouseMove -= MouseMovedCallback;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work only when the cursor is in your application.

XAML

```
<Grid MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove">

</Grid>
```

Code Behind

```
System.Timers.Timer timer;

public YourConstructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Create a timer with a ten second interval.
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
    timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

    // Raise the Elapsed event only once.
    timer.AutoReset = false;

    // Start the timer.
    timer.Start();
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Mouse has not moved for 10s.
}

private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Reset the timer.
    if(timer.Enabled)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
    timer.Start();
}
```

More info about [System.Timers.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I like this solution more, but you should use the DispatcherTimer instead of a simple Timer: otherwise won't work.

Comment: @MarioVernari This will work assuming that no UI updates are done in OnTimedEvent. In that case, add Dispatcher.Invoke, or use the DispatcherTimer as you suggested.